# facebook like returns Error finding the requested story

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to use FB SDK to do a like on a postId.

The post is in a 3rd part fb page.

Usually it works. But when I try to do like few days after the post was created I get this response:

```
Error finding the requested story
```

here is my code:

```
Request request = new Request(session,
        takeFromPublicMacrosOrServer(currentOffer.fbPostId)
                + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,
        new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                // Request complete
                if (response.getError() == null) {
                    UnlockRequestToServer unlockRequestToServer = new UnlockRequestToServer(
                            mOffersListActivity,
                            PublicMacros.TYPE_UNLOCK_FB_LIKE,
                            currentOffer.fbPostId);

                } else {
                    final String errorMsg = "error: "
                            + response.getError().toString();
                    Log.e(MyLogger.TAG, errorMsg);
                    mToaster.showToastInUiThread(errorMsg);
                }
                String re = response.toString();
            }

        });

request.executeAsync();
```